# Return Javascript Variable in Ajax Response

Tags: php, ajax, variables, return, response

HOW TO USE eval() FUNCTION HERE
ajax.js

```
 var x="hello world";
 var y="anyother string";
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax.php",
        success:function(data){
            console.log($.globalEval(data));
        }
    });
```

ajax.php

```
<?php exit("'first string is '+x+' second one is'+y");?>
```

I want to return x,y as a variables to ajax response, so console.log(data) can print value of

```
first string is hello world second one is another string
```

but it says "x is undefine"

**NOTE : I need the solution without passing x and y as data from ajax**

Comment: why don't you directly access "x" variable in ajax response?
like console.log(x);

Comment: here in my case, data is a long HTML string with a lot of variable which values are in javascript.

Comment: Now your Question is understoodable.

Comment: thanks, i just modified my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript can make use of the `eval()` function to parse the string you get from `PHP`. For a simpel example I have dropped the ajax call to get the request in the next example, but you get the idea. [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Km7/) has a working example.

```
<script>
var x="hello world";
var y="anyother string";

//normally you would get this from ajax
var str = "'first string is '+x+' second one is'+y";

//complete will contain the full string after eval.
var complete = '';
eval('complete=' + str);


alert(complete); //first string is hello world second one isanyother string
</script>
```

Now in your case, when you do use AJAX, it would become

```
<script>
var x="hello world";
var y="anyother string";

$.ajax({
  url:"ajax.php",
  success:function(data){
    //complete will contain the full string after eval.
    var complete = '';
    eval('complete=' + data);
    console.log(complete);
  }
});
</script>
```

Now the above is the actual answer to your question, I would still advise against it. See [why is using the javascript eval function a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

To have something like this without eval, you could use something like

```
<script>
var x = "hello world";
var y = "anyother string";

//normally you would get this from ajax
var str = "first string is {x} second one is {y}";

//complete will contain the full string after eval.
var complete = str.replace('{x}', x).replace('{y}', y);

alert(complete); //first string is hello world second one isanyother string
</script>
```

Comment: you deserve for +50, stackoverflow allow me to release +50 in next 16hours

Comment: Take your time, i'm not in a hurry :) Glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

ajax.js:

```
  $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url:"ajax.php",
        data: {x: "helloworld", y:"another string"},
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

ajax.php:

```
echo "First string: ".$_POST['x'].", second string: ".$_POST["y"];
```

Comment: i have modified my question, please review

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to create an echo script, whereby you send a variable via AJAX to your PHP script, and your PHP script returns that value back?

If so, you need to provide `x` in the `data` setting for your AJAX request, as so;

```
var x="helloworld";
$.ajax({
    url:"ajax.php",
    data: {
        x: x
    }
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

And then in your PHP script, you need to retrieve the value from the `POST` array, and output it as the response:

```
<?php
exit($_POST['x']);
```

**EDIT**

To include a second variable (`y`)

```
var x="helloworld",
    y="another string";
$.ajax({
    url:"ajax.php",
    data: {
        x: x,
        y: y
    }
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

and in PHP;

```
<?php
$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];
exit("First string is $x, second string is $y");
```

I would strongly recommend finding some tutorials on JavaScript and PHP basics to get an understanding of some of these concepts

Comment: i have modified my question, please review

Comment: I think, from what I've shown you, you can at least try to figure out how to add a second variable. I'm not your code monkey.

Comment: i know but i can't pass variable like that. It some thing use of eval function

Comment: You don't need to use `eval` to achieve this. Can you update your question to include your attempt at solving this for 2 variables?

Comment: i am using $.globalEval(data) but it through error "x is undefine"